# Scraping Company Names using Node.js and Cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

url = http://www.simon.com/mall/anchorage-5th-avenue-mall/stores

The url above lists all the stores in a specific mall.  What I want to do is scrape from that link to get a list of all the stores in that mall.  This is the code that I have so far

```
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {

        var $ = cheerio.load(body);

        $('h2.card-secondary-title.name.copy').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text();
            console.log(text);
        });
    }
})
```

where the webpage is in this format

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <main id="simon" class>
          <section class="directory">
            <div id="root">
              ...
               <div class="directory-grid row">
                 ...
                   <h2 class="card-secondary-title name copy">5th Avenue Deli</h2>
```

I can't even scrape a single store from the website. Using this method, I've been able to scrape off of a number of other websites but for some reason this one won't work

Comment: may be the reason is because the loading of the store list takes time after you get the first answer (it's ajax loaded) hence you might want to check for a specific component before iterating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to scrape, is loaded via ajax, you won't be able to retrieve it with cheerio.

You can replicate the ajax request directly, to retrieve the information in a JSON format. The data you're looking, comes from this request:

`https://api.simon.com/v1.2/tenant?lw=true&mallId=231`

Which contains the following:

```
[
  {
    "brandId": 48,
    "name": "5th Avenue Deli",  // This is the value you want
    /** ... */
    ]
  },
  /* ... */
]
```

> I'm pretty new to javascript so I have no clue what you mean when you
>   say I should replicate the ajax request directly. Could you explain in
>   a little more detail?

An easy way to replicate an Ajax call, is by checking the request on chrome developers tool (`F12`)

Then go to `network tab` > `XHR filter` > `locate the request` > `right click` > `copy` > `copy as cURL`

Then from curl to any lib you want to use on your server side, it's very easy to convert.

Comment: I'm pretty new to javascript so I have no clue what you mean when you say I should replicate the ajax request directly.  Could you explain in a little more detail?

Comment: Thanks, that works!  I'd give you an upvote but I don't have enough reputation haha